# tomcat7 server - can't install into Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: server, eclipse, tomcat7

I installed:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Tomcat7 at `/usr/local/tomcat7`

When I start tomcat `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` and go to `myIp:8080` I see [correct page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKHwz.png)

And now when I want to add tomcat7 at eclipse (at server view) I choose:

`add new server => choose tomcat7` the finish button is disabled.

[image: tomcat looking]

I can't figure out why this happen.

I can install other servers for example - Jboss

[image]

But why I couldn't add new tomcat server?

**How to solve this trouble?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common bug in Eclipse. To resolve it:

- Close eclipse
- In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings, delete:
  `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` and `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs` files
- Restart Eclipse

That's all. You can check this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163390/2114786) which refers to this other [source](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/453143/).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Tomcat is stopped first before adding it in Eclipse. You do not need to start or stop Tomcat outside Eclipse because you can do it inside Eclipse.

You may be forgetting to fill up the Server name textbox. Next button will be ungreyed once you filled up that textbox.
[image: Define a New Server]

Upon clicking Next you need to specify the Tomcat installation directory (if you downloaded a binary) as highlighted in the Tomcat installation directory textbox. You can also click Download and install button if you don't have Tomcat yet or if you just want to be sure of that you want have the right version.

[image: Tomcat Server]

You can either click Next or Finish. Click Next to add a previous project to Tomcat. Otherwise click Finish to return to your current perspective.

[image: Add and Remove]

After returning to your perspective, just in case you are not in Java EE perspective, do this: From the menu bar click Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Java EE. As you can see at the bottom I have selected the Servers tab and my newly created Tomcat server is already there and was stopped. You can start or stop this server by right clicking it.

[image: Java EE Perspective]

Comment: No I can not type in that field (first slide), I stumbled across this problem and could not figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

just goto windows->preference search or type in box server and select default filesets then select tomcat version and click add  to add the tomcat folder

Click Apply and then ok